# Android 5 - Change default audio input route to use external USB card on Streaming

Tags: android, audio, input, usb, mixer

I'm trying to use a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Android 5.1.1 (rooted) as an basic audio/video live stream equipment but I can't route audio from an external USB card Behringer UCA202 Class Compliant 1.0 to default phone camera application.

Default camera app has the option to create a live event on Youtube and works great, but unfortunately only can get audio from internal speaker as I expected. The sound card is working and I can get sound using others audio record apps.

Any option to change default Audio Input from internal mic to USB Audio IN? Maybe AlsaMixer is the way to go? I look for some kind of virtual mixers on PlayStore but unsuccessfully.

The only post I see asking something similar is this one:
[Change Android Audio Record Default Input Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360512/change-android-audio-record-default-input-source)
but it's from three years ago :(